# Haskell Monads implementation

Tags: list, haskell, syntax, lambda, monads

I was recently reading learn you a haskell and I came across the expression:

```
[1,2] >>= \n -> ['a', 'b'] >>= \ch -> return (n, ch)
```

This expressions returns the result

```
[(1,'a'),(1,'b'),(2,'a'),(2,'b')]
```

so i understand that the monadic bind for lists is implemented as follows

```
xs >>= f = concatMap f xs
```

Taking the first half of the expression namely the:

```
[1,2] >>= \n -> ['a', 'b']
```

it evaluates to `['a','b','a','b']`, from what I understand this is then fed in to the function: `(\ch -> return (n , ch))`.

What I don't understand is how the values 1,2 from the list are assigned to n and then how the compiler keeps a record of it to then assign it to n in the last function?

Comment: ***Omitting explicit parentheses in learning material is Evil.*** Too harsh? Ask countless newbies who loose countless hours because of this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The first half is not what you think, the parentheses are like this :

```
[1,2] >>= ( \n -> ['a', 'b'] >>= ( \ch -> return (n, ch) ) )
```

Comment: You might want to mention that this is because lambda expressions always go as far to the right as possible.